# Find and replace regular expression (matching unicode character class Devanagari) in multiple files

Tags: command-line, perl, regex, text-processing

Say you have a file named `test.txt` with the following lines:

```
ಕದಂಬ
कदम्ब
```

Then, suppose you want to replace each devanagarI unicode character (ie in कदम्ब) with a D. Then, you might think that the following would work:

```
find . -name 'test.*' | xargs perl -w -i -p -e 's/(\p{Devanagari})/D/g'
```

But it doesn't. How to accomplish this?

Comment: You may need to use the `-C` command-line option or set an empty `PERL_UNICODE=` variable: see the [perlrun documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by steeldriver, you can force both STDIN/STDOUT to be UTF-8:

> -C on its own (not followed by any number or option list), or the empty string "" for the PERL_UNICODE environment variable, has the
>   same effect as -CSDL. In other words, the standard I/O handles and the
>   default open() layer are UTF-8-fied but only if the locale environment
>   variables indicate a UTF-8 locale.

```
find . -name 'test.*' 2>/dev/null | xargs perl -w -C -i -p -e 's/(\p{Devanagari})/D/g'
```

Will transform your sample file like this:

```
ಕದಂಬ
DDDDD
```

Source: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches