# Command-line perl regex replacement: replacement string contains utf8

Tags: command-line, perl, regex, text-processing

Say you have a file named `test.txt` with the following lines:

```
ಕದಂ.ಬ
कदम्ब.
```

Then, suppose you want to replace each dot following a devanagarI unicode character (ie in कदम्ब) with a ।. Then, you might think that the following would work:

```
find . -name 'test.*' | xargs perl -w -i -C -p -e 's/(\p{Devanagari})\./$1।/g'
```

But it doesn't (I see the dot in the end replaced with à¥¤).

How to fix the above?

Edit: The below works, but I wanted something more readable:

```
find . -name 'test*'|xargs perl -C -w -i -p -e 's/(\p{Devanagari})\./$1\x{0964}/g'
```

(This is a follow up to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600947/find-and-replace-regular-expression-matching-unicode-character-class-devanagari).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell perl that the script body contains UTF8 chars:

```
$ perl -w -C -p -e 's/(\p{Devanagari})\./$1।/g' test.txt
ಕದಂ.ಬ
कदम्बà¥¤

$ perl -Mutf8 -w -C -p -e 's/(\p{Devanagari})\./$1।/g' test.txt
ಕದಂ.ಬ
कदम्ब।
```